# I can't login to the frontend of my webshop

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, frontend, login, cookie

First i want to say that i'm pretty new to Magento.

Setting up a shop is going pretty well as I can say for myself.

Now when i make myself a member, i get a nice email with some information and a verification link. When i click this link i'm logged in to my site. When i log out and try to login again nothing happens. No errors and i stay on the login page. I read something about cookies but as i told already im pretty new to Magento.

I work with directadmin and Magento 1.9.0.1. Can someone please tell me step by step how i can fix this.

Already thanks for your help.

Comment: have you install any custom theme?

Comment: I installed the hellowired theme.

Comment: can you please give me that theme link?

Comment: http://www.hellothemes.com/themes/hellowired/

Comment: Is there someone who can help me?

Comment: still not I am very busy

Answer (score 1):

When you try to sign in, and the page simply refreshes with no error it means something went bananas with the cookies. For me, this happens frequently if there are two dev sites sharing the same root domain like:

- south.domain.com
- north.domain.com

Often while logging into the other admin, the cookies chomp themselves and the same thing happens.

## The Quick Fix

Clear your browser cache + cookies.

## The Nicer Fix

Deleting all your cookies is annoying. In Chrome, open Developer Tools > Resources. Just delete the `frontend` cookie and refresh the page. That always works for me.

[image: Chrome dev tools cookies]

Answer (score 0):

Open your

> /app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php

find the method `public function loginPostAction()`

and put following code:

```
Mage::log('step 1', false, 'customer.log', true)
```

After each row, increasing step number every time. you will have following:

```
public function loginPostAction()
{
Mage::log('step 2', false, 'customer.log', true)
    if (!$this->_validateFormKey()) {
Mage::log('step 3', false, 'customer.log', true)
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
        return;
    }
Mage::log('step 4', false, 'customer.log', true)
    if ($this->_getSession()->isLoggedIn()) {
Mage::log('step 5', false, 'customer.log', true)
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
        return;
    }
    $session = $this->_getSession();
Mage::log('step 6', false, 'customer.log', true)
    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
Mage::log('step 7', false, 'customer.log', true)
        $login = $this->getRequest()->getPost('login');
        if (!empty($login['username']) && !empty($login['password'])) {
            try {
Mage::log('step 8', false, 'customer.log', true)
                $session->login($login['username'], $login['password']);
                if ($session->getCustomer()->getIsJustConfirmed()) {
Mage::log('step 9', false, 'customer.log', true)
                    $this->_welcomeCustomer($session->getCustomer(), true);
                }
            } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
...
```

Then show us the result. `Don't forget to revert all changes!!!`